# Alpha-beta pruning with checkers

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I would like to implement an artificial intelligence for the checkers game. I must not understand the principle of alpha beta pruning because nothing works!!
I would like that the algorithm stops at a certain time (5 or 10 secs). But, I think with my algorithm, it never stops. In addition the algorithm never cuts branch.

EDIT:
I have those errors:

```
    File "player.py", line 61, in min_value
    v = min(v, self.max_value(pBoard, single_move, pDue, alpha, beta))
    File "player.py", line 44, in max_value
    v = max(v, self.min_value(pBoard, single_move, pDue, alpha, beta))
    File "player.py", line 61, in min_value
    [...]  
    File "player.py", line 61, in min_value
    v = min(v, self.max_value(pBoard, single_move, pDue, alpha, beta))
    File "player.py", line 44, in max_value
    v = max(v, self.min_value(pBoard, single_move, pDue, alpha, beta))
    File "player.py", line 61, in min_value

    TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < float()
```

If someone could explain clearly the process to implement, I would be very grateful.
Here's what I have written with python:
The "evaluation" function gives a value relative to the position of a piece on the board.

```
    def calc_move(self, pBoard, pDue):
       score =0
       validMoves = pBoard.find_possible_moves(CELL_OWN)
       for move in validMoves:
          pBoard.do_move(move)
          score_move = self.max_value(pBoard, move, pDue, -float('inf'), float('inf'))
          if score_move > score:
             score = score_move
             best_move = move
       return best_move

    def max_value(self, pBoard, move, pDue, alpha, beta):
      if pDue - time.time() < 0.5 or move.is_EOG():
         return self.evaluation(move, CELL_OWN)
      v = -float('inf')
      validMoves = pBoard.find_possible_moves(CELL_OWN)
      for single_move in validMoves:
          pBoard.do_move(single_move)
          v = max(v, self.min_value(pBoard, single_move, pDue, alpha, beta))
          if v >= beta:
             return v
          alpha = max(alpha, v)
      return v

    def min_value(self, pBoard, move, pDue, alpha, beta):
      if pDue - time.time() < 0.5 or move.is_EOG():
         return self.evaluation(move, CELL_OTHER)
      v = float('inf')
      validMoves = pBoard.find_possible_moves(CELL_OTHER) 
      for single_move in validMoves:
         pBoard.do_move(single_move)
         v = min(v, self.max_value(pBoard, single_move, pDue, alpha, beta))
         if v <= alpha:
           return v
         beta = min(beta, v)
      return v
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "nothing works!!"  This is vague.
"it never stops."  This is vague.  What do you mean by "it"?  Which function?  All of these use `for` so they look like they'll terminate.  "In addition the algorithm never cuts branch."  If it never stops, then the "never cuts a branch" part doesn't mean much, does it?  Please add `print` statements to display what is going on at various points inside this code.  Without `print`, we're all just guessing.  After adding `print`, please include example output that shows what's wrong.

Comment: `TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < float()` is nothing like "nothing works" and "it never stops".  That's an actual error message.

Answer (score 3):

`File "player.py", line 61, in min_value` and `TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < float()` are important hints.   You should consider that actual error messages are more important than almost anything else you said about the problems you're having.

Since you didn't read the error message, you left it to us to guess which line is line 61.

There are, some comparisons (i.e., `min()`, `if v <= alpha`) in that function that seem relevant.

The error message suggests that `v` is `None`.

Since `v` can come from the value of `return self.evaluation(move, CELL_OWN)`, it looks like `self.evaluation` is returning `None`.  This often happens because of no `return` or a `return` without an expression.

Comment: +1 code should always build/run without errors. Forget algorithmic correctness issues until these are resolved.